# PC won't connect to domain

Tags: networking, windows-10, dns

So, we have a PC that we removed from the network temporarily, due to lack of use. we have since brought it back, with zero change to the network, so everything should remain the same. However, it doesn't recognize the network, and the network doesn't recognize it.

In the network:

- The PC still remains part of the group(s) in AD and DHCP; identified via MAC Address, and PC Name.
- Firewall rules allow network and internet access to IP (granted via IP reservation to above mentioned MAC address).
- Ethernet cables all show connectivity and activity on the appropriate cables (through switch).
- All IPs are correct (PC; DNS Server and Gateway).

On the PC:

- It identifies an "unknown network", and default the profile to either Public or private, with no internet access.

  - I have tried to set the profile to domain by resetting the domain settings in the System Advanced Settings, as well as setting it in the regedit (it would default back to 0 or 1 after I set it to 2 after disabling/re-enabling the Ethernet adapter).
  - I have tried to specify the suffix in the DNS advanced settings of the IPv4 configuration in the Ethernet adapter
  - I have tried a `ipconfig /release` and `/renew` (in Administrator Command Prompt), and it simply replies with "cannot perform while media is disconnected"
  - `ipconfig` reports all the correct IP configuration, yet still won't identify the network.

Pinging the network (e.g the server) from the PC (using both IP and AD name) results in 100% package loss, as does pinging the PC from anywhere else in the network.

Comment: Is the PC currently using static or DHCP-retrieved network settings?

Comment: I have tried both.